# How to programmatically get the folder above the /data/user/0/com.companyname/files location on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I need to get the folder above the /data/user/0/com.companyname/files location which is the folder returned by the System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal / System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments code. As outlined in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) these two have the topmost level.

The problem is that on native Android, SQLite generates a database on the /data/user/0/com.companyname/databases/ location. How do I programmatically navigate to this location?

Comment: GetDatabasePath : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getdatabasepath?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Content_Context_GetDatabasePath_System_String_

Comment: `/data/user/0/com.companyname/files`. First remove /files and then add /databases/location.

Comment: If you want you can show us the code of what you are trying to do, and we can fix it up

Comment: This really helped me out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586596/net-maui-writing-files-that-a-connected-computer-can-see